# How to enable the user to correct the situation display?

Tags: android, geolocation

in a geolocation application, after the recovery of the location I will like to let the user correct the situation by draggable marker on the map.

example: in the image the true position is the red cross then the solution is to drag the blue marker and confirm.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is done by CommonsWare [here in this link](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/src/com/commonsware/android/maptouch/NooYawk.java)

Solution is to make one `Overlay Class extending the ItemizedOverlay` that you might have created to draw the marker on the map.

Now int that Custom Overlaty Class you will `need to Override the onTouch event`.
while in that

1. MOVE event you set the position of the marker at moveded X and Y
2. ACTION UP event you can take the X - Y and convert it into GEO POINT using this
   `mapViewmap.getProjection().fromPixels(x,y)` that is your current marker's geo point.

FOR BETTER UNDERSTANDING AND PRACTICAL EXAMPLE YOU CAN GO TO THE ABOVE LINK.

Comment: By 5k rep you should know better than to post link-only answers. See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) and its several related posts.

Comment: @LordTorgamus yeh and I have my answer posted over there also you might have seen that too ... and for this particular question there is a working example on the link..so no point in copy paste that code here...

Comment: Can you elaborate on this answer a little?

Comment: @NullUserException Will edit the SELECTED ANSWER, Ok. If have any doubts regarding the Question feel free to ask.. will try as much I can.

Answer (score 1):

Not so nice approach but way easier to implement: show the center of the map with a little cross plus put a button somewhere that says "use map center" or so. Getting map center from google maps is quite easy.

The map start initially centered at the user (blue marker). Now the user drags the map so the center(*) of the map is where he is actually located (red cross). Then user hits the button. You take the location of the map center then and can update the location + marker of your user.

(*) You need something that indicates the center of the map so the user can see where that is.

Comment: I do not know what you're talking about? you misunderstood what I am looking ... 

I have users using geolocation, then the application can return precise coordinates monks, so I want to give the user the opportunity to correct the position on the map.
if possible, how?

Comment: I guess (hope) I understood what you want. I've updated my answer to make it a little more clear what I said. Basically you just use the builtin map controls (instead of implementing some drag and drop for the marker) to let the user select a new position. That worked pretty well for me in a little location based service app that lets you correct the gps location (the blue marker in your image) to the real location (red cross) by just dragging the map so the red cross is in the center.